# Why is @ConfigurationProperties annotation not part of the spring-core project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I understand `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation was initially developed as part of the spring-boot project... but the functionality `@ConfigurationProperties` can be applied outside the spring boot project with any other spring project... given that premise....

How come  `@ConfigurationProperties` is not part of the core-framework?

Is this a subliminal hint that all new enhancements to spring "core" framework  will only be made to the sprint-boot project and hence forth all new projects should be using spring-boot?

Comment: That annotation is part of a bigger more complex feature, so inheriting would not be that easy. Spring Framework is trying to be more robust, stable and compact in some sense. I am pretty sure that if it makes sense to inherit something from Boot to Spring, the developers would do it. Just like they did it with part of Spring Integration. (This question feels like it should be asked on Spring's forum / mailing list)

Comment: @Pavel Horal Spring forums no longer used. "This forum is now a read-only archive. All commenting, posting, registration services have been turned off. Those needing community support and/or wanting to ask questions should refer to the Tag/Forum map, and to http://spring.io/questions for a curated list of stackoverflow tags that Pivotal engineers, and the community, monitor."

Comment: ... and your answer doesn't really provide the reasoning/logic behind keeping the annotation in spring-boot only. How is it "more robust" to limit an optional feature to spring-boot only? I asked the question looking for the specific reason. On the surface it doesn't really make any sense to me that this feature would only be in spring-boot. Property injection applies to any spring project.

Comment: Interesting... I didn't know they closed the forums in favour of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends what you mean by core. The line you have to draw is regarding opinionated approach vs. framework/generic/configurable features. `@ConfigurationProperites` uses a relaxed binding that is *very* opinionated so it can't move to Spring Framework itself. It also considers that your properties start with a certain prefix. Again, it's an opinion that works great with Spring Boot but may be a bit too restrictive for the framework.

In any case, I think the issue is a bit artificial. You could perfectly add the `spring-boot` artifact to your "non" Spring Boot project and use that feature if you really wanted to but you should probably wonder what's stopping you from using Spring Boot (New features usually require a dependency upgrade).

Comment: well I didn't want to add spring boot only to use ConfigurationProperties annotation seems a bit overkill and would the annotation even be scanned and validation triggered if I am using a non boot spring project (runner)?. My use case is I want add to a spring4 project multiple ConfigurationProperties annotations that utilize jsr-303 validation and map (via reflection api) the class attribute names to the entries in the .properties files. Also, the prefix is injectable per ConfigurationProperties annotation per use instance... so I don't see how this is 'opinionated' to spring-boot only.

Comment: For instance, if i have rabbitmq.properties, mongodb.properties, somethingelse.properties. How is creating a corresponding RabbitMQProperites.class, MongoDBProperties.class, SometihngElseProperties.class all annotated with ConfigurationProperties "opinionated" to Spring-Boot only? I want to leverage the sanity checks and jsr-303 validation provided by the ConfigurationProperties annotation